# Why do we use the Laplacian matrix in Spectral Clustering?

Tags: laplacian, spectral-graph-theory, clustering, graph-laplacian

When we perform spectral clustering, given a similarity matrix $S$, we define the Laplacian matrix $L$ (normalized or unnormalized). Then, we do eigenvalue decomposition on $L$ and get its eigenvector matrix.

Why do we do eigenvalue decomposition on $L$, and not on the similarity matrix $S$?

It seems that a graph's spectrum (i.e. the eigenvalues of its Laplacian matrix) contains the structural information of a graph, but why? Why does it explain the graph structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why the Laplacian?

The main idea in Spectral clustering is:

1. Find a graph representation of the data
2. Find a partition of the graph into $k$ highly inter-connected and lowly intra-connected 'clusters'

Step 2. can be reformulated as finding the [minimum 'cut'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut) of edges required to separate the graph into $k$ components.

It turns out* that minimising the value of the cut is equivalent to minimising a function of the **Laplacian** $L = D - W$:

$$\min_{A_1,...,A_k} \textrm{Tr}(H'LH) \textrm{ subject to } H'H = I$$

Where the columns of $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ are the indicator vectors of the $k$ vertex sets $A_1,...,A_k$ partitioning the graph.

**Note:** the solution of this is in general NP-hard given the definition of $H$, but a relaxed version where its entries can take any real value is solved by choosing $H$ as the matrix which contains the first $k$ eigenvectors of $L$ as columns.

These eigenvectors span a space containing a lower dimensional embedding of our graph, within which (due to the nature of the minimisation problem) our clusters are now easily separable.

## Properties of the Laplacian

Intuition for this may be motivated by recognising the Laplacian has several useful properties absent in the adjacency matrix:

- The smallest eigenvalue of $L$ is $\lambda_0 = 0$ and its multiplicity equals the number of connected components in the graph.
- The eigenspace of $\lambda_0$ is spanned by the indicator vectors of those components.
- $L$ is singular
- $L = UU^T$ where $U$ is the incidence matrix of the (arbitrarily directed) graph (and hence $L$ is positive-semidefinite)

---

**Further reading**

<sup>* See Chapter 5 of the following document for a full derivation:</sup>

> <sup>... the main trick is to change the representation of the abstract data points $x_i [∈ \mathbb{R}^n]$ to points $y_i ∈ \mathbb{R}^k$. It is due to the properties of the graph Laplacians that this change of representation is useful. We will see in the next sections that this change of representation enhances the cluster-properties in the data, so that they can be trivially detected in the new representation. In particular, the simple k-means clustering algorithm has no difficulties to detect the clusters in this new representation.</sup>

<sup>- [A Tutorial on Spectral Clustering](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10701/readings/Luxburg06_TR.pdf) (2006)</sup>

<sup>For further reading, see the original papers proposing he method:</sup>

> <sup>Spectral clustering goes back to [Donath and Hoffman](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5391366) (1973), who first suggested to construct graph partitions based on eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix. In the same year, [Fiedler](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/101168/CzechMathJ_23-1973-2_11.pdf?sequence=2) (1973) discovered that bi-partitions of a graph are closely connected with the second eigenvector of the graph Laplacian, and he suggested to use this eigenvector to partition a graph.</sup>

<sup>Note Fiedler himself states prior to this the Adjacency matrix (and incidence matrix) were indeed previously used to characterize graphs:</sup>

> <sup>We recall that many authors, e.g. A. J. HOFFMAN, M. DOOB, D. K. RAY-CHAUDHURi, J. J. SEIDEL have characterized graphs by means of the spectra of the $(0, 1)$ and $(0, 1, —1)$ adjacency matrices.</sup>

Comment: when is the normalized symmetric laplacian preferred over the standard Laplacian?